# Retrieving NEW DropdownList.SelectedIndex in Page_Init()

Tags: asp.net, page-init

Although I have gathered many answers from stackoverflow, this is the first question I am posting. So kindly forgive any gaffes in abiding any protocol. I am trying to fix a situation since 3 days. I have read large chunks of pages on internet, but failed to get any solution (which I think must exist!).

Problem: Lets say, I have 3 dynamic controls created in Page_Init, ddl1 (DropdownList), ddl2 (DropdownList), txt3 (Textbox). Based on the SelectedIndex of ddl1, I enable or disable ddl2 **within the Page_Init**. Based on SelectedIndex of ddl2, I enable or disable txt3. This can go multiple times.

The first time I load my page, I fetch the value of ddl1 from database to determine whether ddl2 should be enabled or disabled. This works fine.

The ddl1 and ddl2 have dynamic event handlers for SelectedIndexChanged like:

```
ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(EnableDisableEventHandler);
```

Now, if user changes the item in ddl1, the Page_Init is fired, followed by the ddl1 event handler at the end. The problem is, I want to determine the NEW SelectedIndex of dd1 in Page_Init() so that I can enable/disable ddl2. As the page is not rendered, I cannot use FindControl. I am using a Panel, which has a table, which has rows, which has cells, which has these controls – if this information helps. I have tried to determine the new value using this table (for ddl2, ddl1 is already added to table). However, the table doesn’t have the NEW SelectedIndex.

Please let me know if there’s a solution to this problem. I can handle the SelectedIndexChanged event and run the Enable/Disable logic again. However, this makes the page horribly slow.

Please help.

Many thanks,
Bhushan

Comment: You need to show the code, so that we can simulate the issue.

Comment: Use Page_Load for this. "As the page is not rendered, I cannot use FindControl." - what does that mean?

Comment: Where is the code that creates ddl1 and ddl2 located? Why would you need to use FindControl if you already have ddl2 reference?

Comment: if you are creating dynamic controls each time it will be different.how will you get selectedindex?and in page_Init as per my understanding view state will not be loaded so how will you get the data?best place in my opinion is page_load

Comment: Thanks all!

First, the ddl1, ddl2 and txt3 (there are about 100 such dynamically created controls) - all are created in Page_Init. The event handling and AutoEventWireUp doesnt work when the controls are created in Page_Load(). More about it in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

@shreesha Yes, the changed SelectedIndex is not accessible in Page_Init() as the ViewState is not loaded. Moving enable-disable logic to Page_Load() makes the system extremely slow.

Somehow I feel there must be a way to access the old page ddl1.SelectedIndex after postback.